# Pronunciation of Emma and Emma's

Tags: pronunciation, names, ipa, weak-vowel-merger

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Emma#Pronunciation), Emma is pronounced as /ˈɛmə/ but I tend to hear it sounding more like /ˈɛmɑː/. However, when it comes to pronouncing *Emma's*, I hear it like /ˈɛməz/ and I hear a clear schwa there.

Here are the samples for /ˈɛmɑː/ (Watch them at 0.25x playback speed):

**British**: [1](https://youtu.be/LIYiThAyY8s?t=288), [2](https://youtu.be/Bks4JX95dD8?t=52), [3](https://youtu.be/rnwYDKUpiws?t=525), [4](https://youtu.be/SEfz8U2Xt1A?t=50), [5](https://youtu.be/vQo3VpPvpzY?t=299), [6](https://youtu.be/aP6cs5aM-O4?t=7480)

**American**: [1](https://youtu.be/akOe5-UsQ2o?t=632), [2](https://youtu.be/V4mUAjGTiQI?t=77), [3](https://youtu.be/P70EBWzpZXM), [4](https://youtu.be/JRci2V8PxW4?t=70), [5](https://youtu.be/6sSQZw6G2yA?t=295), [6](https://youtu.be/5r3kpyp0qs0?t=8), [7](https://youtu.be/dM3pd4dR7v4?t=138), [8](https://youtu.be/GqpC3aP_6qg?t=2693)

**Australian**: [1](https://youtu.be/Z3RZInvbOIQ?t=9), [2](https://youtu.be/E1a0GiGJePQ?t=331), [3](https://youtu.be/aRAsslbbS5E?t=37), [4](https://youtu.be/juVfakuowCA?t=1278)

If you listen to the samples at 0.25x speed, you'll notice that the letter a in /ˈɛmɑː/  sounds longish compared to letter a in in /ˈɛməz/.

Here are the samples for /ˈɛməz/ (Watch them with 0.25x playback speed): [1](https://youtu.be/Kbeo7lFs698?t=1856) , [2](https://youtu.be/lnaO_9A6AYw?t=93) , [3](https://youtu.be/Bks4JX95dD8?t=496)

I must say the length of the letter *a* in the Aussie accent is somewhat longer compared to other samples.

Assuming Wiktionary is incorrect, why is it that Emma's pronounced as /ˈɛməz/ instead of /ˈɛmɑːz/?

Comment: Wiktionary is not incorrect. I at least have never heard anyone pronounce the name _Emma_ as /ˈemɑː/ in English. There is a somewhat similar word that does have this option: the word _cinema_ is most commonly pronounced /ˈsɪnəmə/ everywhere nowadays, but in the UK, it used to be (and among some older speakers still is) the norm to pronounce it /ˈsɪnəmɑː/. But that doesn’t apply to _Emma_, which has only ever been /ˈemə/ in recent history.

Comment: This may be a regional thing, or even a particular person's preference. Where do you hear /ˈɛmɑː/?

Comment: I certainly say  /ˈsɪnəmɑː/ when it is final in a breath-group.

Comment: @ColinFine I hear it in my ears. I have very sharp ear. The ending of Emma has that long ɑː sound instead short schwa.  I am not an expert in IPA.

Comment: @FinAnalyst: Of course you hear it in your ears. We hear everything in our ears. I meant, what part of the English-speaking world do you hear it in? But actually, now you say that, I think there is a (perhaps stereotypical) London teen accent that has /-ɑː/ in a lot of words.

Comment: @ColinFine I hear it in both US and UK. Please checkout the samples I mentioned above. The sound of  a ending in the word Emma's is shorter compared to the word Emma. I don't know the right IPA symbol to illustrate this.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I definitely wouldn't go that far about the pronunciation of cinema. I've only 28 and pronouncing it with a full vowel sounds entirely natural to me

Comment: this could really do with links to examples where you hear a clear `/ˈɛmɑː/`. None of the examples I went through here https://youglish.com/pronounce/Emma/english? had a full /-ɑː/

Comment: @ColinFine ime that very lowered and backed schwa is more of an Essex "chav" feature than a London one

Comment: I've listened to the first two links that you added for "Emma", and I hear perhaps a slightly lowered final vowel, but definitely not /-ɑː/. I haven't listened to any more.

Comment: @ColinFine Check the Aussie one please. What do you mean by lowered final vowel?

Comment: Y'all are listening phonemically, not phonetically. There are many different vowel qualities in that collection. None has the vowel of "pa", "law", so it is phonemically /ʌ/ → further reduced to some vague vowel in final unstressed position. The tokens in those recordings are not internally identical – they are not "absolute [ɑ]" or anything else. It is whatever phoneme you use for unstressed noun-round non-high final vowels.

Comment: @user6726 Did you direct that comment to me or to the others?

Comment: Everybody. Your Tube examples do not all have the same phonetic final vowel. The first US example is close to canonical [ɑ], the third is closer to [a]. Nice collection of tokens BTW.

Comment: @user6726 Thanks, it is from Youglish. Everbody says that they don't hear ɑː in `Emma` but I do. It is long as opposed short sound in word `Emma's`.  I am not a Linguist btw.

Comment: @user6726 note that most Americans don't actually have a distinction between /ʌ/ & /ə/, so anything phonemically /ʌ/ is just as reasonably called phonemically a schwa (for the American tokens)

Comment: Or, anything phonemically /ə/ is just as reasonably called [ʌ] when stressed. There's no phonological basis for imputing specifically /ʌ/ quality to the phoneme.

Comment: the British tokens definitely sound longer in Emma than Emma's, but the vowel is way too high and front to be called [ɑ:]. As for cause it may be related to the fact the syllable is open in Emma, but closed in Emma's. In the US and AU tokens it also sounds too high to me, maybe nearer variously ɐ, ʌ, or ä depending on the speaker, all longer than the truly short vowel in Emma's

Comment: @SirCornflakes, is it your view that all linguistic questions about English should be migrated to ELU, unless they invoke a highly sophisticated theoretical concept?

Comment: @user6726 sure, but when the question uses a framing of this as a schwa, it's probably best to either stick to describing them as schwas, or at least explicitly flag that you're not doing so, and considering them merely unstressed allophones of ʌ

Comment: @user6726 Most of them, indeed. BTW, I am always ready to change my mind when a good answer containing a sufficient amount of linguistics appears here.

Comment: @Tristan "all longer than the truly short vowel in Emma's " - This is what I was talking about. So there is no IPA symbol for this? I used ɑ: because it sounded like that to my ears.

Comment: @Tristan I used schwa because it is the sound I know for uh sound / the shorter vowel you mentioned. I am not an Linguist let alone IPA expert. I am working on accent reduction.

Comment: @Tristan Though the question is about why they don't use longer vowel for Emma's.

Comment: @FinAnalyst: The word *Emma* has a longer vowel than *Emma's*, but it's still an /ə/ and not an /ɑː/. Compare the word *Emma* with the word *enchanting* in your first link https://youtu.be/LIYiThAyY8s?t=288. They are clearly different vowels to my ears. The length of the vowel is ***not*** the only difference between /ə/ and /ɑː/.

Comment: @FinAnalyst: You ask: "So there is no IPA symbol for this?" It's not a separate phoneme. The short vowel in *Emma's* and the somewhat longer vowel in *Emma* are both allophones of the phoneme /ə/ (which is longer at the end of a word), so we use the same IPA symbol for them. If you really wanted to, you could the symbol [ˈɛmə̆z] for *Emma's* ([ə̆] can be used in IPA for an extra-short vowel) and [ˈɛmə] for *Emma*. This would be a narrow transcription and not a phonemic transcription, and so not used by dictionaries.

Comment: @FinAnalyst There are other English vowels that lengthen at the ends of words, as well. Compare *happy* and *happiness*.